# jcarousel width issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jcarousel

I'm using jCarousel on a website I'm creating for my company. I'm using the default javascript that came with jCarousel.

```
<ul id="mycarousel" class="jcarousel-list jcarousel-list-horizontal" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative; top: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; left: 0px;width: 2084px;">
```

The width is being generated by the javascript that jCarousel came with but I can cypher though it to figure out where to change the value.

Any help would be great.

Here is a link to what I'm working on: http://marcbrigham.com/lynxems/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-clip-horizontal {
    width:  245px;
    height: 75px;
}
```

Taken from the default Tango skin that´s used in the [examples](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/static_simple.html).

What skin/theme/CSS are you using? jCarousel needs to change the `width` to enable the slide but the wrapper element should be using `overflow: hidden;`.

**UPDATE**

This CSS edit makes it look OK but if you need it to cover the whole width of `#mainhome` you should consider changing the size of the images.

```
.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-container-horizontal {
  width: 765px;
  padding: 20px 40px;
  height: 200px;
}

.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-clip-horizontal {
  width: 775px;
  height: 190px;
}
```

Another option could be adding `margin: 0 40px;` to `.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-clip-horizontal`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also create a CSS style and add `!important` to it, which will override the inline styles. For example:

```
#carousel {
    width: 1000px !important;
}
```

While this works, I'm finding that if the container is too wide, you'll be able to scroll beyond just the items within it. I'm still looking for a workaround for this.

There's also a new version (0.3.0) but there aren't any really good examples on the developers site yet.

Answer (score -1):

just add a style to your css:

`.jcarousel-list-horizontal {width: x}`

Al

Comment: I don't believe that will work since the inline style will overwrite the width in the stylesheet